# Why does \newcommand on an already defined active character not yield an error?

Tags: latex-base, active-characters

We (or at least I) usually think of an active character as just another command whose name just happens to a character rather than a control sequence. So why does `\newcommand<active character>` not yield an error if the `<active character>` was already defined?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\newcommand{coffee} % error

\newcommand~{coffee} % no error

~

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interestingly, `\newcommand\~{coffee}` does give the error.

Comment: @Marijn Not really surprising as `\~` is an actual control sequence with an existing definition that is completely different from that of `~` (right, `se\~norita`)?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right - I somehow mistakingly thought that `~` was a shorthand for `\~` but that doesn't make sense. By the way I'm a señor :)

Comment: @Marijn I guessed as much, but perhaps the señorita I asked was the lovely lady standing right behind you (with a gun to the back of your head). `;-)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with any "why" command about latex the answer is related to the token memory available in 1985 (2.0x) or 1993 (2e)

This century things are different

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}



\NewDocumentCommand~{coffee} % no error

~

\end{document}
```

gives

```
! LaTeX cmd Error: Command '~' already defined.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.8 
    
?
```

Answer (score 1):

An answer looking at the source code: First we have the macros `\@ifundefined` and `\@ifdefinable`:

[image: ifundefined and ifdefinable documentation]

Note that `\@ifundefined` takes in *strings* (technically "the name of the control sequence") as the argument, not the control sequence itself.

However `\@ifdefinable` takes in a *control sequence* as the input. So if it wants to *use* `\@ifundefined` in its implementation, it has to extract the name:

[image: source code of ifdefinable]

It's not too hard to see the check only works for control sequences, not active characters.

Side note, assuming nobody wants to use this command when `\escapechar` is -1 or 32 (space character), it would work correctly.

Side note 2, `\@ifundefined`, contrary to what its name implies, is supposed to<sup>(*)</sup> check if the argument's meaning is **either `undefined` or `\relax`**.
Nevertheless, it first uses `\ifcsname ... \endcsname` to check if it's `undefined` first, then if it is not, construct the control sequence with the name to check if it's `\relax`, presumably to
save an entry in the hash table when the name is not defined.
(I suspect in pre-ε-TeX days, only the csname-relax check is performed, then after that the ifcsname
is added in to save an entry; but to maintain backwards compatibility it still need to check if the meaning is \relax -- although I didn't check this in the old LaTeX source code)

[image: source code of ifundefined]

Maybe someone who can find want source code of older LaTeX versions can confirm that these versions use just the csname-\relax check.

<sup>(*)</sup>: Or so I think.

Comment: you can see the date of change and the old definition in the current sources, to allow rollback via `latexrelease`: `% \changes{1.5c}{2018/01/06}{Avoid defining undefined commands to \cs{relax}}`